# Hierarchy in array (php) -> how to get parent?

Tags: php, arrays, parent, hierarchy

I have a hierarchy in array and i'd like to know how can i "move" from children to parent.
Is there a better way to work with php and hierarchy?

I'd like to avoid using recursive steps for each child i need to check a parent.

Is there a class or something similar? As exists with xml?

Comment: Can you post an example?

Comment: Please provide complete, concise [sample](http://sscce.org/) of what you have. Right now, the data structure and knowns are unclear. Are you saying you have a reference to a child, and you want to find the array that contains it from a multidimensional array?

Answer (score 0):

Spl comes with various data structures. Perhaps you are looking for one of them : https://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.datastructures.php